# How to use docker compose to make changes to application's configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way I can make changes to my application's configuration before deployment?
I have 2 appservers that are connected up in a network. I have set the host endpoint in a config file call setting.json on the client.

{
"host_url" : "http://0.0.0.0:3201",
}

But I will be required to change this port number depending on production environment requirements. (Deployment done by another engineer using docker compose).

Is there any way I can set the host_url in the docker-compose and I tell him to change to the host_url depending on the requirement.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Why not use environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a configuration like below. The app will use redis based on the REDIS_HOST set as the redis service. Similarly the MYSQL_HOST will be set to the db service.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports: "6033:3306"
  app:
    build: .
    ports: "12345:8990"
    env:
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

If the deployment should be different between development and production, the compose files should set different environment variables in each scenario for the application to pick up.

```
web:
  environment:
    - PORT
```

In CLI -

```
docker-compose run -e PORT=3201 web
```

At this point the `PORT` environment variable is available for your application to get the value from.

---

A separate environment file can be created for convenience too.

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

Complete documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/